# image of product of functions mapping unit disk to unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Find image of $|z|\leq1$ For $$w=\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{z_k - z}{1-\bar{z_k}z}$$ where $0<|z_k|<1$

I know if I write $w=f_1 f_2...f_n$ for $f_k=\frac{z_k -z}{1-\bar{z_k}z}$ then $f_k$ maps $|z|\leq 1$ onto itself. thus f must map $|z|\leq 1$ to itself. I think $f$ will be also onto since $n=1$ is such a case. but I don't see how to proceed.

Comment: you mean the unit circle or the unit disk? Generally the [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) is understood as the boundary of the unit disk, that is, when $|z|=1$

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If $f$ maps $|z| \leq 1$ onto itself, how can it not be onto?

Comment: I mean unit disk and its bound

Comment: I know $f_k$ is surjective. but how can I assure $f$ is also surjective? I only know $f(x)$ belong to unit disk if $x$ is in the disk. If  I pick any $\alpha$ in the unit disk, then I have to show $\alpha = f(z)=f_1(z)...f_n(z)$ for some $z$ in unit disk but I'm not sure about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the argument principle. Since $f$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of the closed unit disk, and $\lvert f(z)\rvert = 1$ for $\lvert z\rvert = 1$, the number of times $f$ attains $w$ (counting multiplicity) in the open unit disk is given by

$$N(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{f'(\zeta)}{f(\zeta) - w}\,d\zeta$$

for $w \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\lvert w\rvert \neq 1$. As a continuous integer-valued function $N$ is locally constant on its domain $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{w : \lvert w\rvert = 1\}$, so it is in particular constant on the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. But clearly $N(f(0)) > 0$, so $N(w) > 0$ for all $w \in \mathbb{D}$. Thus

$$\mathbb{D} \subset f(\mathbb{D})\,,$$

and since $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is compact we have

$$\overline{\mathbb{D}} \subset \overline{f(\mathbb{D})} = f(\overline{\mathbb{D}})\,.$$

Comment: I haven't learned holomorphic function yet. This problem belongs to bilinear transformation parts.. differentiable and analytic functions are not introduced yet. Is there any other approach I can use?

Comment: You should have stated that in the question. When you tag a question [tag:complex-analysis], it's quite natural to assume that you already know what holomorphic functions are, unless you say that you don't. Yes, there are other approaches. If you know a bit about rational functions, you can use that $f$ is a non-constant rational function, and hence attains every value in $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$. Since $\lvert z\rvert > 1 \implies \lvert f_k(z)\rvert > 1$ for every $k$, it follows that all values $\lvert w\rvert \leqslant 1$ are attained in the closed unit disk.

Comment: But without knowing what has been treated so far, I don't know what method may be appropriate.

Comment: I use complex analysis with applications(silverman) and dealt with only bilinear transformation(cross ratio, inversion of circle and straight line,classification of bilinear transformation mapping circle/disk/line to circle/disk/line)

Comment: and I see that your idea using rational function will suffices to show what I wanted. thanks!